# How I can make my python module useable once after each 10 Mint

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I'm new here sorry for any mistake

i just want to make this module use only after 10 mint once useable if user use this command user have to wait 10 mint to use this again

Here is my code

```
def refresh_admin(update, _):
    try:
        ADMIN_CACHE.pop(update.effective_chat.id)
    except KeyError:
        pass

    update.effective_message.reply_text("I have refreshed")
```

Comment: Are you using a database for this bot?

Comment: Yes I'm using psql

Comment: ok then you can use column for each user with time,  you should include last refresh time and then you can check deference current time and last refresh time if gap is grater then 10 m you can pass other wise send a error message

Comment: can you help and give an example ?

Comment: Yah sure I'll add it to here